# Syntax issues when uploading backup from mysql5.7 to percona xtradb 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, errors, percona, syntax

**Greetings to those readying the thread and thank you for devoting your time to answering the question.**

I have encountered a problem when uploading a MySQL 5.7 backup database to a Percona xtradb 5.7 cluster.

The restoration is performed by the mysqlfrm command in the following format.

`mysqlfrm -q --user=root '--server=root:password@localhost:3306' --port=3310 /location/of/backup/directory --diagnostic | mysql -B -u username -p'password'`

**Basic explanation of the command:**

The command concatenates the .frm files and then pipelines them to the MySQL shell to be executed.

Now... when uploading the .frm files and performing the "CREATE TABLE" Statement I have noticed that the query contains "ROW_FORMAT = 5".
The results when uploading the backup to mysql5.7 where successful and all the data was restored but when performing the same for a Percona xtradb 5.7 cluster I was presented with a syntax error "ERROR 1064".

**This is an example of the query:**

`CREATE TABLE example.test (node_id INT PRIMARY KEY, node_name VARCHAR(30))ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8, ROW_FORMAT = 5, COMMENT 'test';`

When changing the ROW_FORMAT = 5 to Compact everything is working and the restore is successful.

Now for the main question does MySQL 5.7 and Percona xtradb 5.7 have a difference between syntaxes and is it at all normal that when performing the backup the .frm file has captured the value of 5 to the ROW_FORMAT variable instead of Compact?

Comment: Did you try running the same CREATE TABLE statement on MySQL? I don't think ROW_FORMAT=5 will work regardless of which branch you use. This appears to be an error in the output of mysqlfrm.

Comment: Suggest filling a bug report with Percona.

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to find my answer.

It does seem as if the MySQL utilities package downloaded from the yum repositories for centos7 has a bit of a problem with its version.

After redownloading it from the official MySQL repositories I was successful to restore the .frm tables.

The working version is "MySQL Utilities mysqlfrm version 1.6.5".